# Как поменять изображения слайдера при переходе в мобильную версию

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин

подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность менять изображения слайдера при переходе в мобильную версию, то есть не размер изображения, а именно само изображение?

Comment: Средствами css - нет. С помощью js - да

Comment: Почему css нет? Если у него в слайдере картинка может выводиться, как бекграунд, допустим RevSlider

Comment: @eugene_v, а есть еще какие то аналоги RevSlider? Например в smart slider можно решить такую проблему?

Comment: А в Smart Slider - ccs скорее всего нет, как писал KAGG - js. Но я сужу по вот этой демке https://smartslider3.com/wordpress-post-slider/. Самим плагином не приходилось пользоваться, возможно там есть какое-то решение для моб. устройства.

Comment: В теге `img` можно также задавать определенные `src` (тоесть саму картинку) в замвисимости от разрешения экрана.